# How can I use Roboguice dependency injection in adapter android

Tags: java, android, roboguice

**What i have done:** 
I am aware of using dependency injection of Roboguice in activity like below

```
 @InjectView(R.id.listView) ListView listView;
```

**Question:**

### How to use this in a

### CODE

**From activity I am calling adapter like below::**

```
AdptOrderListHome tickets = new AdptOrderListHome(getActivity(), result.getProducts());
listView.setAdapter(tickets);
```

**AdptOrderListHome.java**

```
public class AdptOrderListHome extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<InventoryProductItems> mProducts;

    private Context mContext = null;

    public AdptOrderListHome(Context context, ArrayList<InventoryProductItems> products) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
        mProducts = products;
        Log.d("",mProducts.size()+"");
        Log.d("",mProducts.size()+"");
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mProducts.size();
    }

    public InventoryProductItems getItem(int position) {
        return mProducts.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        final ViewHolder vHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {


            LayoutInflater layout = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layout.inflate(R.layout.row_order_list_home, null);
            vHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
            view.setTag(vHolder);
        } else {
            vHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        //Set the tag
        vHolder.txtProductNameId.setTag(mProducts.get(position).getProduct().getId());

        vHolder.txtProductNameId.setText(mProducts.get(position).getProduct().getName());
        vHolder.txtInStockId.setText(mProducts.get(position).getCurrent_Product_item_Count()+"");
        vHolder.txtRbProductsId.setText(mProducts.get(position).getRB_Product_item_Count()+"");



        return view;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtProductNameId, txtInStockId, txtRbProductsId;
        private LinearLayout root;

        public ViewHolder(View base) {
            txtProductNameId = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.txtProductNameId);
            txtInStockId = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.txtInStockId);
            txtRbProductsId = (TextView) base.findViewById(R.id.txtRbProductsId);
            root = (LinearLayout) base.findViewById(R.id.root);
        }
    }

}
```

### EDIT

```
  class ViewHolder {

        @InjectView(R.id.txtProductNameId) private TextView txtProductNameId;
        @InjectView(R.id.txtInStockId) private TextView txtInStockId;
        @InjectView(R.id.txtRbProductsId) private TextView txtRbProductsId;

        public ViewHolder(View base) {
            RoboGuice.getInjector(base.getContext()).injectViewMembers(mContext);
        }
    }
```

---

**error:**

1. mContext giving me error in line

   RoboGuice.getInjector(base.getContext()).injectViewMembers(mContext);

   `Cannot resolve method inject view members`

[image: snapshot]

Comment: As explained in my comment, you should use `RoboGuice.getInjector(base.getContext()).injectViewMembers(this);` if you want to inject the views in your ViewHolder. Not sure why you are getting this error though, the method definitely exists

Comment: @ nicopico ... please check the snapshot .... should i need to do anything other than that like passing some thing to adapter related to roboguice than the one i posted

Comment: Can you try with `injectMembers` instead of `injectViewMembers` ?

Comment: Tried it ... app crashes .... i guess we have to do some thing more to adapter also

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the source of [`RoboActivity`](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/master/roboguice/src/main/java/roboguice/activity/RoboActivity.java) to see how it is done.

Basically, you need to call `RoboInjector.injectViewMembers()` in the constructor of your viewholder. Something like this:

```
class ViewHolder {
    @InjectView(R.id.txtView)
    private TextView txtView;
    @InjectView(R.id.imgView)
    private ImageView imgView;

    public ViewHolder(View root) {
        RoboGuice.getInjector(root.getContext()).injectViewMembers(this);
    }
}
```

Note that this will only *View Injection*.
If you want to do *Dependency Injection* (with `@Inject` fields), you should use `RoboInjector.injectMembersWithoutViews()`.

Comment: Which version of RoboGuice are you using? Also, the parameter passed to `injectViewMembers` should be the one holding the `@InjectView` annotations (in this case, the `ViewHolder` instance)

Comment: I am using `org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0-alpha-2` ..........  I have extended `RoboActionBarActivity` ... and the fragment in it has extended `RoboFragment` ... the adapter is on  the fragment